# SQL Query to remove associated records that all don't meet certain condition

Tags: sql-server, query

I have the following tables and values in a 2014 SQL Express Server. They have been simplified to focus directly on the issue I'm having and for brevity.

```
Tbl_Contact
-ContactID

Tbl_Opportunity
-OpportunityID
-totalAmount

Tbl_Contact_Opportunity
-ContactID
-OpportunityID
```

This is the query I started with:

```
select * from Tbl_Contact
inner join Tbl_Contact_Opportunity on Tbl_Contact.ContactID = Tbl_Contact_Opportunity.ContactID
inner join Tbl_Opportunity on Tbl_Contact_Opportunity.OpportunityID = Tbl_Opportunity.Opportunity.ID 
where Tbl_Opportunity.totalAmount=0
```

This query returns a list of all the `Tbl_Contact.ContactID`s that have a `Tbl_Opportunity` with a `totalAmount`=0. But I don't want that.

What I want to is to write a SQL query to list all the `Tbl_Contact.ContactID`s that have **all** of their corresponding `Tbl_Opportunity`s with a `totalAmount`=0. I don't know how to do this.

For example take the following tables:

Tbl_Contact

| ContactID |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |

Tbl_Opportunity

| OpportunityID | totalAmout |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 321 |
| 2 | 0 |
| 3 | 0 |
| 4 | 0 |

Tbl_Contact_Opportunity

| ContactID | OpportunityID |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 2 | 4 |

with the query I wrote above the result would be:

| ContactID |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |

but the result I really want is:

| ContactID |
| --- |
| 2 |

That is because **both** of the `Tbl_Opportunity`s associated with `ContactID`=2 have the `totalAmount`=0. Where `ContactID`=1 doesn't have both `Tbl_Opportunity`s associated with it having value `totalAmount`=0. One of them is 123, so I don't want that included in the query result.

Can someone help me rewrite my query to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you seem to want only `ContactID` in the output and only distinct values thereof, it is enough to employ regular grouping and aggregation for this and use just the tables `Tbl_Opportunity` and `Tbl_Contact_Opportunity`, as they have all the required data.

Your query would be as simple as this:

```
SELECT
  co.ContactID
FROM
  dbo.Tbl_Contact_Opportunity AS co
  INNER JOIN dbo.Tbl_Opportunity AS o ON co.OpportunityID = o.OpportunityID
GROUP BY
  co.ContactID
HAVING
  COUNT(CASE WHEN o.totalAmount <> 0 THEN 1 END) = 0
  -- another option: COUNT(NULLIF(o.totalAmount, 0)) = 0
;
```

The `COUNT` function above will count only the rows that have a non-zero `totalAmount`, giving you the number of such rows per group, i.e. per `ContactID`, since `ContactID` is the grouping term.  You want contacts without non-zero amounts, therefore you just match the result of the `COUNT` to 0 in the `HAVING` clause to give you corresponding groups – or `ContactID` values.

Answer (score 0):

One way is you can use a [window function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) and a [CTE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to check the value of all of the `totalAmount`s of each partition of `ContactID` for any non-0 values like so:

```
WITH _ContactAmounts AS
(
    select *,
        MAX
        (
           CASE
               WHEN Tbl_Opportunity.totalAmount <> 0 THEN 1
               ELSE 0
           END
        ) 
        OVER (PARTITION BY Tbl_Contact.ContactID) AS HasNonZeroAmount
    from Tbl_Contact 
    inner join Tbl_Contact_Opportunity 
        on Tbl_Contact.ContactID = Tbl_Contact_Opportunity.ContactID 
    inner join Tbl_Opportunity 
        on Tbl_Contact_Opportunity.OpportunityID = Tbl_Opportunity.Opportunity.ID
)

SELECT *
FROM _ContactAmounts
WHERE HasNonZeroAmount = 0 -- Filters out all of ContactID rows who had at least one row with a non-0 totalAmount for that ContactID
```

Note you should also explicitly list out the columns you want to `SELECT`, using `SELECT *` is bad practice for readability, maintainability, debugability, and even performance.